# How do I restrict my Elasticsearch database traffic to the IBM private network?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have an IBM Cloud Databases for Elasticsearch deployment. How can I set the endpoints to only allow traffic from the IBM Cloud private network?

Answer (score 3):

By default, a deployment of IBM Cloud Databases for Elasticsearch will be created with public endpoints, i.e. it will be accessible from the public internet.

If you want to restrict traffic to the IBM private network you can use the IBM CLI to switch off the public interface and enable the private interface only.

You can install the CLI [from here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli) and you will need to add the cloud databases plugin with:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cloud-databases
```

Log into the IBM Cloud CLI with:

```
ibmcloud login -sso
```

Follow the on-screen instructions to log in.

You can then list all the database deployments in your account with:

```
ibmcloud cdb ls

#Name                          Location   State
#Databases for PostgreSQL-76   us-south   inactive
#testelastic                   eu-gb      active
#Databases for MySQL-9j        us-south   active
#Databases for MongoDB-ky      eu-gb      active
```

You can then set the deployment to Private Endpoints by doing:

```
ibmcloud resource service-instance-update testelastic --service-endpoints private
```

IBM Cloud Databases for Elasticsearch allows both public and private endpoints to be used simultaneously. To do that, set the `service-endpoints` parameter to `public-and-private`

NOTE that if you change the endpoint type, the connection string for your database deployment will also change, so your application configuration will have to change.

There is more information on private and public endpoints in the [Cloud Databases Documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-elasticsearch?topic=databases-for-elasticsearch-service-endpoints)